# Bootstrap modal opens only by clicking twice on the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

```
---------home.html----------
<html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>

<script src="main.js"></script>
<script src="aboutController.js"></script>
<script src="sharedDataService.js"></script>
<script src="sampleController.js"></script>
<script src="profileController.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="aboutController">
<div class="col-md-8" style="text-align:center; width:190px; margin-top:160px;">
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#/profle">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#/modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="col-md-10" style="text-align:center; margin-top:70px;" ng-view>
</div>
</div>

</html>

------main.js----------
angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]).config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when("/go", {
    templateUrl : "sample.html",
controller : "sampleController"
})
.when("/profile", {
    templateUrl : "profile.html",
controller : "profileController"
})
.when("/modal", {
    templateUrl : "modal.html"
})
.otherwise({
    templateUrl : "profile.html",
controller : "profileController"
  });
     });

-------modal.html-------
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

I am creating a test app in angularjs. I am using Bootstrap modal which is supposed to open up when I click on "Messages" link in the home.html page.And routing also takes place on the click of that link but when I click on this link, routing takes place but Bootstrap modal doesn't open on first click on the link but when I click again on the link, it opens up. Can someone tell me why is this happening? And what's the fix for this?

Comment: It happens because when you click on modal link, the template has not yet loaded in the dom.

Comment: @Santosh So what do I do now? I want the modal to open up on the very first click.

Comment: If the /modal only opens the modal on loading the route, then you can create a controller for it and load the modal programatically.

Comment: Basic example of bootstrap modal in angular 
http://embed.plnkr.co/jwNjrXCjMRLk5Jg79nTw/preview